# How do I find out the XPath to the <Result> tag in this XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I get this response from a service I am calling. I wish to write an assertion in Soap-UI to validate the value of the `<Result>` tag.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ServiceResponse> <!--Issue happens here when xmlns attribute is present-->
            <ServiceResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/services.api.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <AdditionalInfo i:nil="true"/>
                <ErrorMessage/>
                <ErrorMessageId i:nil="true"/>
                <ErrorMessages xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                <InternalId>0</InternalId>
                <RecordsAffected>0</RecordsAffected>
                <Result>false</Result>
                <WarningMessages xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
                <a:ReturnBase>
                </a:ReturnBase>
            </ServiceResult>
        </ServiceResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I used the [Xpath Testing tool online](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) to find a correct path. When I remove the xmlns attribute on the `<ServiceResponse>` tag, the XPATH works as expected. However when I have the `xmlns="http://schema.Services"` on the `<ServiceResponse>` tag, XPath fails to return an item.

I also tried to find this in Notepad++ with the XML Tools Plugin and it throws an exception when I have the `<ServiceResponse xmlns="http://schema.Services">` in there.

How can I go about writing this assertion in soap-UI?

Comment: You missed to provide the XPath expression for selected the `Result` element, which is problematic. A likely cause is that you haven't correctly specified the namespace bindings to the XPath processor that you are calling to evaluate the XPath expression. Which exactly XPath processor are you using? Please, *edit* the question and provide this important, missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of XML namespaces is that you can assign arbitrary prefixes to them.

So if your XML uses a default namespace, you can just make up a prefix for it:

```
declare namespace s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace serv='http://schema.Services';
/s:Envelope/s:Body/serv:ServiceResponse/serv:ServiceResult/serv:Result[. = 'false']
```

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI uses Saxon XPath / XQuery processor, so you have XPath 2.0.  One of the nice things about XPath 2.0 is namespace wildcarding, so you can do this:

```
/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:ServiceResult
```